# indication before Computer going to crash

Tags: computer-science, cpu-usage, cpu-architecture

Is there any way to know the computer(system) is going to crash within few minutes or seconds?

Can we know using the clock pulse or CPU overhead? Can anyone please help to clear this thing

Thanks in advance

Comment: Dig into the concept of [RAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reliability,_availability_and_serviceability), particularly the R. It is possible to detect HW faults up to some degree (I'd say: reliability:pain = hw fault:death), without a specific system it's hard to give a short answer. When HW begins to fall apart a lot of unpredictable behaviours show up, including slowed down functionality but usually CPU overhead is unrelated and the clock per sè is rarely a source of HW errors. But again, this depends on the system (e.g. a slow clock may be the symptom of a faulty PM unit).

Comment: Only if the crash is planned.  e.g. write a program which prints "crash in 2 minutes", then crashes your computer!  After running that program, you know your computer will crash within 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really cannot predict when a computer is going to crash. A reliable operating system does detailed hardware error reporting. When you start seeing a lot of hardware errors in the log, you know that crash is coming.

That only deals with hardware-related crashes. A system can crash due to software problems an those can occur with no warning at all.